# Paypal express is redirecting to paypal gateway instead of displaying payment in pop up

Tags: magento2

I am having issue that in my magento 2 site I am using paypal express but at front end when we click on paypal express at checkout. it is redirecting to paypal site instead of displaying pop up to payment. Please let me know how to enable pop up/ modal box payment window. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable `Enable In-Context Checkout Experience` to `Yes` In order to make payment via popup.

Store > Settings > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods > PayPal Express Checkout > Required PayPal Settings > set Enable In-Context Checkout Experience to “Yes"

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this

Comment: but I have one ques after this paypal credit button is also showing. how to remove this?

Comment: Set Enable PayPal Credit to `No` @Stackuser

Comment: but this option is not listed under settings. I know it should be under enable this solution but  it is not present at my end.

Comment: Please check the screenshot, I can see 4th option

Comment: yes but somehow its not displaying in my settings instead there is a feature tab which state Disable Funding Options. I guess here I need to register it. but I dont know which string should I paste here.

Comment: check this. it has same problem like me: https://community.magento.com/t5/Payments-PayPal/how-do-I-disable-the-paypal-credit-button-on-Paypal-Express/td-p/134768

Comment: please ask a new question for this, so community members can answer this :)

Comment: Thanks and no need now, found the solution here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22243